# Random String Generator from list

Tags: java, string, random

Hi I have 3 Strings that I need to be randomly chosen.

```
HeLlo
hELLo
HElLo
```

I need a simple code to randomly choose between those three options.

Comment: there are about one trillion duplicates of this question is you take the time to search for them.

Answer (score 1):

Make an array of your strings..
Then choose randomly

```
String[] array = String[]{"HeLlo","hELLo","HElLo"};
    array[(int)(Math.random()*3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This makes an array of Strings and choses a random index from 0 to 2.

```
Random r = new Random();
String[] list = {"HeLlo", "hELLo","HElLo"};
System.out.println(list[r.nextInt(3)]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Java Code**

```
import java.util.Random; 
public class TestProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] myStringArray = {"HeLlo","hELLo","HElLo"};
        Random generator = new Random();
        int randomIndex = generator.nextInt(myStringArray.length);
        System.out.println(myStringArray[randomIndex]);
    }   

}
```